# Select distinct while also grouping by hour

Tags: mysql, count, group-by, distinct

I have have this query but cannot make it work properly when I specify a distinct count.  I know the syntax must be off somewhere but I am at a loss where.

The group by query that accurately counts by hour is:

```
SELECT HOUR(dateAdded)  AS Hour,
       COUNT(dateAdded) AS `user_count`
FROM   Track
WHERE  dateAdded BETWEEN '2014-04-01' AND '2014-05-02'
        OR dateAdded IS NULL
GROUP  BY HOUR(dateAdded)
ORDER  BY Hour
```

The new statement with the distinct count adjustments is as follows:

```
SELECT HOUR(dateAdded)                           AS Hour,
       COUNT(DISTINCT remoteAddr, xForwardedFor) AS `user_count`
FROM   Track
WHERE  dateAdded BETWEEN '2014-05-01' AND '2014-05-02'
        OR dateAdded IS NULL
           AND accessMask = '1iczo'
GROUP  BY HOUR(dateAdded)
ORDER  BY Hour
```

I know this might be abstract without reference to actual data, I can update the question if you need it for reference.

**UPDATE**
The answer that was posted put me in the right direction in terms of thinking about the solution but I don't believe it was returning an accurate result.  I came up with this solution instead and in case it is useful for anyone else, posted it.  This can probably be done much better but its what I was able to come up with and gives accurate results.

```
SELECT HOUR( dateAdded ) AS HOUR , COUNT( DISTINCT remoteAddr, xForwardedFor ) AS cnt
FROM Track
WHERE accessMask =  '1iczo'
AND destination =  'lp_include.php'
AND dateAdded
BETWEEN  '2014-05-01'
AND  '2014-05-02'
GROUP BY HOUR
ORDER BY HOUR
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should do that with a subquery

Don't think you can't do a `count(distinct ...)` on two columns.

```
SELECT hour, count(*) as user_count
from
   (SELECT HOUR(dateAdded) AS Hour,
           remoteAddr, 
           xForwardedFor

    FROM   Track
    WHERE  dateAdded BETWEEN '2014-05-01' AND '2014-05-02'
        OR dateAdded IS NULL
           AND accessMask = '1iczo'
    GROUP  BY HOUR(dateAdded), remoteAddr, xForwardedFor) s
group by hour
order by hour
```

Comment: Wow thanks a lot!  I am new to sub-queries but will now have to research them more to leverage them.  Is http://dev.mysql.com/ the best place to learn more complex mysql statements or do you know of a better place for reference/learning?  Thanks again!

Comment: @user3613676 well, know the doc is always a good thing, then when I'm stuck I just usually google...

Comment: Thanks again.  I may have spoken too soon, I dont believe that it is returning the proper results.  I am not sure but I don't understand where you specify the distinct remoteAddr and xForwardedFor?

Comment: @user3613676 well, in the inner subquery, I group by hour(dateAdded), remoteAddr and xForwardedFor. That's what's "replacing" the distinct. Then I group all this only by hour, and count on this in the main query.